# What is Meteor production

Tags: meteor

I have not used the property `Meteor.isProduction` in the meantime.
But I wonder when use it.
Some of the things I know are:

- Returns `true` value when typing `meteor --production` in terminal.
- "hot code push'' does not apply when `true 'state.

Comment: It only simulates prod. Code minification: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#never-use-production-flag

Comment: @Jankapunkt, this only refers to the `--production` flag for the `meteor run` command. The `Meteor.isProduction` property is also true when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `"production"`, and it is obviously meant to tell you if you are running in a production environment, i.e, the one that is meant to serve you application to the actual users, and not for development or testing.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "_"hot code push'' does not apply when `true 'state._". If you need some help for that, you should probably ask a separate question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it when ever you want to do something differently in production and dev modes.

For example you could setup a function as follows to only console.log in dev mode.

```
export function devLog(logMe) {
    !Meteor.isProduction && console.log(logMe)
}
```

Another example would be maybe getting a url for another service you use and in dev you want to use a dev version or mocked out service where as in production you will want to use the production service.

```
export function getServiceUrl() {
    return Meteor.isProduction ? 'https://production.example.com' : 'http://localhost:8080'
}
```

I hope these simple examples give you some idea of the use cases for using Meteor.isProduction.